# Single WCF project will not create build artifact under YAML Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

Our build pipeline includes a YML template that is used to build all of our WCF services and Web applications. For all of the WCF services but one, it works like a charm. For this one WCF service, however, the following output is generated in the build logs during the Publish Artifact stage:

> ##[warning]Directory 'D:\azagent\A2_work\1381\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

Our Build stage invokes a separate YML file which includes the following to build and publish the project:

```
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: "Build ${{ parameters.solution}}"
    inputs:
      solution: ${{ parameters.solution }}
      msbuildArgs: >
        /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
        /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
        /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
        /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
        /p:IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion=true 
        /p:PackageLocation="$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
      platform: ${{ parameters.buildPlatform }}
      configuration: ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Publish Build Artifact"
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
      ArtifactName: "drop"
      publishLocation: "Container"
```

As stated earlier, this works perfectly for all other WCF projects, and generates a build artifact. However, for the problematic WCF Service, no build artifact is generated. What we've observed is that no ZIP file is created in the `D:\azagent\A2_work\1381\a` folder (theoretically, `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`).

I have tried numerous recommended solutions to resolve this issue, all to no effect.

1. Adding a `CopyFiles@2` task between the `VSBuild@1` task and the `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` task did place the files in the `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`, but they were not in a ZIP file. Further, the deployment task (later in the pipeline) failed because no ZIP file was present in the `drop` folder.
2. Adding `/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtfactStagingDirectory)` did seem to produce some sort of artifact, but the deployment task still failed, claiming it could not find the ZIP file in the `drop` folder.
3. I created a test repo that contained only the WCF project (as it's normally contained in a solution containing it and a Web application) and ran the pipeline against that repo. No build artifact was created.

Ultimately, nothing I do seems to be able to get this project to generate a build artifact.

What am I missing here? What further information can I provide that will help you to help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried publishing the project locally in visual studio and checked whether the artifacts are available? and I would also recommend you to check if the value of your build configuration of your project and the value from the parameter is matching.

Comment: If Artifacts are produced fine and if your looking for just to zip it, you can use Archive File Task https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops

Comment: @AnnamalaiD I can publish the project locally in Visual Studio and it creates a folder containing all the files I need to deploy the thing to a web server. However, it will not do so in a build pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/publishing-wcf-service-library-from-pipeline/690257), this has been a known issue since August of 2019. WCF services built using a YAML pipeline do not produce build artifacts. Consequently, they cannot be deployed via YAML pipelines.

As of this date, there is neither a fix nor a workaround available from Microsoft.